# Counting consecutive values from alternate columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I would like to be able to count the highest number of consecutive "true" values from different columns but not from consecutive columns - I have generated an example below with Column H being the column where the results show:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True |  | True |  | True |  | False | 3 |
| True |  | True |  | False |  | True | 2 |
| False |  | True |  | False |  | True | 1 |

So basically, I would want the value in Column H to count the highest amount of consecutive true values from every other column, disregarding any data in the columns I have left empty above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(A2:G,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,max(scan(,choosecols(Σ,sequence(1,round(columns(Σ)/2),1,2)),lambda(a,c,if(c,a+1,)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow, that works fine. Is there a simple amendment to the formula if I wanted to increase the gap to 4 columns between relevant columns - so it would be Col A, Col E, Col I etc that would become relevant instead of every other column>

Comment: replace `sequence(1,round(columns(Σ)/2),1,2)` part with `sequence(1,roundup(columns(Σ)/4),1,4)`

Comment: I overthought that adjustment but now working - thanks for confirming @rockinfreakshow and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
=BYROW(A2:G,LAMBDA(row,IF(COUNTA(row)=0,,MAX(SCAN(,row,LAMBDA(a,c,SWITCH(c,TRUE,a+1,"",a,)))))))
```

Or:

```
=BYROW(A2:G,LAMBDA(row,IF(COUNTA(row)=0,,INDEX(MAX(LEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(,1,LEFT(row)),"F")))))))
```